# Error in WPTouch PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code for my WPTouch Worpress plugin. i tried adding something to it and then removed what I added and now I'm getting an error. What is the issue?

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /home/kyfbnews/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wptouch/core/mobile-user-agents.php on line 18
```

Code:

```
  <?php

/* Smartphones */
global $wptouch_smartphone_list;
$wptouch_smartphone_list = array(
    array( 'iPhone' ),                              // iPhone
    array( 'iPod', 'Mobile' ),                      // iPod touch
    array( 'Android', 'Mobile' ),                   // Android devices
    array( 'Opera', 'Mini/7' ),                     // Opera Mini 7
    array( 'BB', 'Mobile Safari' ),                 // BB10 devices
    array( 'BlackBerry', 'Mobile Safari' ),         // BB 6, 7 devices
    array( 'IEMobile/10', 'Touch' ),                // Windows IE 10 touch devices
    array( 'IEMobile/11', 'Touch' ),                // Windows IE 11 touch devices
    array( 'Firefox', 'Mobile' ),                   // Firefox OS devices
    'IEMobile/7.0',                                 // Windows Phone OS 7
    'IEMobile/9.0',                                 // Windows Phone OS 9
    'webOS'                                         // Palm Pre/Pixi
);

/* Tablets */
global $wptouch_tablet_list;
$wptouch_tablet_list = array(
    // Nothing excluded yet
);

/* Matching any of these user-agents will cause WPtouch Pro to be shown for the 'default' theme */
global $wptouch_device_classes;
$wptouch_device_classes[ 'default' ] = $wptouch_smartphone_list;

global $wptouch_exclusion_list;
$wptouch_exclusion_list = $wptouch_tablet_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the issue right off the bat, so try returning to the default, which is:

```
global $wptouch_smartphone_list;
$wptouch_smartphone_list = array(
    array( 'iPhone', 'Mobile' ),                    // iPhone
    array( 'iPod', 'Mobile' ),                      // iPod touch
    array( 'Android', 'Mobile' ),                   // Android devices
    array( 'BB', 'Mobile Safari' ),                 // BB10 devices
    array( 'BlackBerry', 'Mobile Safari' ),         // BB 6, 7 devices
    array( 'IEMobile/10.0', 'Touch' ),              // Windows IE 10 touch devices
    array( 'Firefox', 'Mobile' ),                   // Firefox OS devices
    'IEMobile/7.0',                                 // Windows Phone OS 7
    'IEMobile/9.0',                                 // Windows Phone OS 9
    'webOS'                                         // Palm Pre/Pixi
);
```

If that fails, then you've got something else going on. If it succeeds, add your new additions one by one, and see which one causes the problem.

Comment: I have returned to the defaults but I think the issue is just that I can't actually update the file via my Wordpress admin page since I can't access anything on it. I think I may need to do it via FTP.

Comment: @user2029585, if the revised file isn't saving, that would be the issue. Changing it back via FTP is going to be your only solution if the admin is inaccessible, but you shouldn't be using the built in Theme Editor/Plugin Editor anyways, as it is a major security risk.